# Como adicionar um header a uma imagem capturada com html2canvas?

Tags: canvas, html2canvas, html5-canvas

estou tentando emitir um comprovante de assinatura em uma pagina, e nela tem a opção de salvar o comprovante como imagem, na pagina do comprovante NÃO tem o header com a logo da empresa e o nome da assinatura, eu quero adicionar isso na imagem mas sem que isso apareça para meu usuário,o código abaixo e o que tenho e gera a imagem perfeitamente do jeito que eu quero, so preciso adicionar um header na imagem com a logo e uma escrita qualquer na frente.

```js
function gerarImagem() {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById('telaPrint')).then(function(canvas) {
    var name = 'img-print';
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      let a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
      a.download = name + '.png';
      a.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      a.remove()
    };
    xhr.open('GET', canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0));
    xhr.send();
  });

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>34571073</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="telaPrint" style="background-color: #fff">
    <pre>
        dsadadadada
        asdadadsada
    
        adadada
    
        adadadasdada
      </pre>
  </div>
  <button onClick="gerarImagem()">img</button>
</body>
```

caso o codigo acima nao fucione pelo cdn tem esse [codepen](https://codepen.io/marcosnikito/pen/abNbOWK).

desculpem pela inexperiência aqui no editor do stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Podemos adicionar o header antes de converter e colocar a imagem codificada em base64.

```
function gerarImagem() {

    var telaPrint = document.getElementById('telaPrint');
    var header = document.createElement("h1");
    header.textContent = "Título";
    telaPrint.prepend(header);
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWgAAADICAYAAADFjnuPAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyRpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+IDx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuMy1jMDExIDY2LjE0NTY2MSwgMjAxMi8wMi8wNi0xNDo1NjoyNyAgICAgICAgIj4gPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4gPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9IiIgeG1sbnM6eG1wPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvIiB4bWxuczp4bXBNTT0iaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wL21tLyIgeG1sbnM6c3RSZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9zVHlwZS9SZXNvdXJjZVJlZiMiIHhtcDpDcmVhdG9yVG9vbD0iQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENTNiAoTWFjaW50b3NoKSIgeG1wTU06SW5zdGFuY2VJRD0ieG1wLmlpZDozQjA2NTY4MzdEMzQxMUU0QUVBMkIwQThFRUM1NzY0RCIgeG1wTU06RG9jdW1lbnRJRD0ieG1wLmRpZDozQjA2NTY4NDdEMzQxMUU0QUVBMkIwQThFRUM1NzY0RCI+IDx4bXBNTTpEZXJpdmVkRnJvbSBzdFJlZjppbnN0YW5jZUlEPSJ4bXAuaWlkOjNCMDY1NjgxN0QzNDExRTRBRUEyQjBBOEVFQzU3NjREIiBzdFJlZjpkb2N1bWVudElEPSJ4bXAuZGlkOjNCMDY1NjgyN0QzNDExRTRBRUEyQjBBOEVFQzU3NjREIi8+IDwvcmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uPiA8L3JkZjpSREY+IDwveDp4bXBtZXRhPiA8P3hwYWNrZXQgZW5kPSJyIj8+nkznnQAABrJJREFUeNrs3Y9t2koAwGHzlAVYgRXoCGSEdIBUSkYgIyQjBKkZIBkBRohHSFZgBIr1DsWNAJ//UXN8n2SpfQF8ubz+chhjRpvNJgNgeEYCDSDQAAg0gEADINAAAg2AQAMg0AACDYBAAwg0AAINgEADCDQAAg0g0AAINIBAAyDQAAg0gEADINAAAg2AQAMg0AACDYBAAwg0AAININAACDQAAg0g0AAINIBAAyDQAAg0gEADINAAAg2AQAMItEADCDQAAg0g0AAINIBAAyDQAKQW6N8vL9//k980wF99K//l1+3t2X0DVwn8EIQZONaG0bl+A/+JM3AhoRZoAATa6hlIuhdW0AACDYBAAwg0AAININAACDQAAg0g0AAINIBAAyDQAAg0gEADINAAAg2AQAMINAACDYBAAwg0AAININAACDQAAg0g0AA0dWUKzt7TdnuouM3mxGP63G5v2y3fbuvttvr29dl2G2+36Xa72W6TE49vN6a8tK1LX5+WttkJxjf0+UKgScAq/LLII26XhSg9hPDMQ3z6Hl+xz0XF7fJv38Nd2KYXNl/8Yw5x0IUiMNdhyxve/2eL+8esUHePv2hw/+I+P0Ic1xcwXwg0iViEUKw6WlE2jWhVXN86eKyn8Fh5wvOFQJNQnO87WlXurMNjLgY6vs8WK9ehzxcCTWJx7kvb6Dz0OL51gxX50OcLgSYReVZ95kgXYl5AOxTDpx7HVbxI95jQfDFQzuKgaQjqPE2fZF+nhn2GLXalWuxrWfMQRJMYzkp/PnZ8eFxzPEOfL6ygScgii3+BqzgN7H27fYRoLMOf37P4U8RWNZ+61znGW0T5Nfv/PPFladv9fd8YlyHSqcwXAk1CYg8dPIf4TQ8cIngNt+lyn6vIGI7D/pdHwjcrjXFc+p6mCc0XAk1C3iKfbhfHZ+8ibncXGZ3dO+26CNO4Isz7xljcfh75PZ3TfCHQJCRmdToLMYt1l/19/LfpvvPI8T02WAXXfVHwHOYLgSbBFXSVeYPHfexg3zHHXWcNVsGpzhcCTWKr56oX36aRq7t996ta1a6z46eQxawY5+YLgSZFMf/Y21y8J+a+qyNjqzrW2zSGKc4XAk1iYl7sanO1t2mLMfQdw9TmC4HmAgPdZoU6azGGvmOY2nwh0CSm6nhqFxeRnzQcQ8wKema+ODfe6k2sqgh2FZzPBmOoClHMO/9WDcc7OcP5QqBhML88Yg5vXDfYb3G629z00xeHOAAEGgCBBhBoLkjVWRBdfcZemzEcsjZfCDSXbv2P7lsVotx8IdCkLOZMiDYhzFuMYdzz2FKbLwSaxMSct9vmafuqxRimHTz+5sCW4nwh0CQm5nhmm0tcvrUYw7TnsaU2Xwg0Ca6gq1ZkTT/JY5VVXzfi2P6LEFUd5oi9oP8lzBcCTYJirgjX5PPwHjrY96yj/VzKfCHQXGCg85rRecq6uVzoXeTY7s0XAk2KYi96X6zwYj6CahG5Gpxl1ceZZ5FP6Yt9XmenuRTnkOcLgSZBsRcHKlaqPw+s9vLwtfuO9/kcebviGO6PELtDq9HPhocfzmm+GDhXs7sMbUIz37M6K54+x7y49Ra2cWlFV8SmzpssbrL4sxHqjG0d5uWpdN9ynLtaYQ95vhBoBqDNi2PzAyvVmA9FLcewyRkU4xqr4vLYYj6jcN+qui9Dni8c4iAxRQiWJ9jPaxb3LsHvY2tyv0udLwSaBE17Xq09t3iqPg1B7DNW45rjG/J8IdAkqDi17b3jEO5Wm3ctH2caxtZHtIrH/Mjqnykx5PlCoEl0JV3EqovzbmcdR3US4vXYURQnYaXaZnU+5PlCoEnQ7rjvsmF4bsJ9l1k/b0+ehyg+Nnz83eGJj45WqkOfLwbCWRx0/dS/2IozKIqzEPLSn7/fbly6/SkiMw6hnmdf1+XYncK2b3yT7OuNJpMLnC8GYLTZbM5y4L9fXjZ+fECsX7e3o3Mbs0McAAINgEADCDQAAg0g0AAINAACDSDQAAg0gEADINAACDSAQAMg0AACDYBAAwg0AAINgEADCDQAAg0g0AAINACpBHrkxwek3AsraACB9lsR0Ik6rhKa/I3/D4GUFnCjzUbXAAQaAIEGEGgABBpAoAEQaAAEGkCgARBoAIEGQKABEGgAgQZAoAEEGgCBBhBoAAQaAIEGEGgABBpAoAEQaAAEGkCgARBoAIEGQKABBBoAgQZAoAEEGgCBBhBoAAQaAIEGEGgABBpAoAEQaACBNgsAAg2AQAMINAACDSDQAAg0AAININAAtPZHgAEASgSjajGP/6kAAAAASUVORK5CYII="
    img.onload = function() {
        telaPrint.prepend(img);
        converter();
        header.remove();
        img.remove();
    }

}

function converter(){

    html2canvas(document.getElementById('telaPrint')).then(function (canvas) {
    var name = 'img-print';
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function () {
        let a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
        a.download = name + '.png';
        a.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        a.remove()
    };
    xhr.open('GET', canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0));
    xhr.send();
    });

}
```